# pandas - Joining CSV time series into a single dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get 4 CSV files into one dataframe. I've looked around on the web for examples and tried a few but they all give errors. Finally I think I'm onto something, but it gives unexpected results. Can anybody tell me why this doesn't work?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 24*365*4
dates = pd.date_range('20120101',periods=n,freq='h')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(n,1),index=dates,columns=list('R'))
#df = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)

paths = ['./LAM DIV/10118218_JAN_LAM_DIV_1.csv',
         './LAM DIV/10118218_JAN-APR_LAM_DIV_1.csv',
         './LAM DIV/10118250_JAN_LAM_DIV_2.csv',
         './LAM DIV/10118250_JAN-APR_LAM_DIV_2.csv']

for i in range(len(paths)):
    data = pd.read_csv(paths[i], index_col=0, header=0, parse_dates=True)
    df.join(data['TempC'])
df.head()
```

Expected result:

```
Date Time   R   0   1   2   3
```

Getting this:

```
Date Time   R
```

Comment: Did you mean to save the result of `df.join(data['TempC'])` into `df`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the result of your join:

```
df = df.join(data['TempC'])
```